# Im getting error in startListening() stopListening()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the code in which I'm getting errors in `startListening()` and `stopListening()`:

```java
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_app_cart,container,false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recylervieww);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        cartmodelList = new ArrayList<>();
        cartadapt = new cartAdapter(getActivity(),cartmodelList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(cartadapt);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Cartmodel> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Cartmodel>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart List"), Cartmodel.class)
                        .build();

        cartadapt = new cartAdapter(options);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(cartadapt);


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        cartadapt.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        cartadapt.stopListening();
    }
}
```

This is the code for cartAdapter:

```java
public class cartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<cartAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<Cartmodel> cartmodelList;

    public cartAdapter(Context context, List<Cartmodel> cartmodelList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cartmodelList = cartmodelList;
    }

    public cartAdapter(FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Cartmodel> options) {
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public cartAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart_singlero,parent,false));

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull cartAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.productName.setText(cartmodelList.get(position).getProductName());
        holder.quantity.setText(cartmodelList.get(position).getQuantity());
        holder.totalPrice.setText(cartmodelList.get(position).getTotalPrice());
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(Cartmodel.productImage()).into(holder.productImage);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cartmodelList.size();
    }

   

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView date,productName,productPrice,quantity,totalPrice;
        ImageView productImage;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            productName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pnametext);
            quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            totalPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.totalprice);
            productImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img2);

        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting these errors:

> Cannot resolve method 'startListening' in 'cartAdapter'
> Cannot resolve method 'stopListening' in 'cartAdapter'

I'm using both classes in another activity but in those, I'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting error in startListening() and stopListening()

Because those methods are **not** present inside [RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter) class. Your adapter class should extend [FirebaseRecyclerAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java) class instead in order to be able to call `startListening()` and `stopListening()`.

For more info, please check the official documentation:

- https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/database/readme/

Comment: hey..Thanks for the answer..Plz take a look at my new question it is very urgent its related to firebase real time database
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75449885/data-is-not-displaying-in-cart-from-firebase

Comment: Hey Aditya. Can I help you with other information regarding this question?